# Difference between SessionHandler::destroy and session_destroy?

Tags: php, session

I'm working on a secure session class which extends `SessionHandler` and I'm just wondering whether there's any difference to using the `destroy` method from SessionHandler and using `session_destroy` ?

The only noticeable difference I can find is that `destroy` takes a session $id param.

Comment: Without knowing what this custom SessionHandler class does in its destroy() method, how can you expect us to answer this question?

Comment: Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/sessionhandler.destroy.php seems to call http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php

Comment: @MarkBaker Not a custom class. Docs can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandler.php